# How to say that you saw something with a verb?

Tags: grammar, syntax, nominalization

I know how to say "I saw a cat" 「猫を見た」. However once a verb get's involved I'm not so sure anymore. I have two ideas on how to say it. The sentences is suppose to read "I saw someone being in that house over there".

> あの家に誰かいると見た
>
> あの家に誰かいることを見た

I don't know if either of those sounds any good. How would you report seeing something that involves a verb? Rephrasing it without the verb is not allowed unless you have a way to do it with all verbs and nouns. Also if there exist a nuanced way of saying it that implies that what is being seen is still ongoing, please share that as well. Like I saw a person there and he is still there.

Comment: I'm not sure your example sentences are the best, since they are more natural *without* the いる（あの家に誰かを見た）

Comment: @oals Yeah, I think "I saw someone in that house over there" is more natural in English too. Even so, this was the actual sentence I wanted so I decided to use it as an example, even if there is another way to phrase it.

Comment: Well you could try something like replacing the word "being" to get "I saw someone eating in that house".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you could say...

- あの家に｛誰かが/誰か｝いる**の**を見た。

or maybe:

- あの家に｛誰かが/誰か｝いる**ところ**を見た。

> 「XXがYYするのを見る」「XXがYYするところを見る」 "see XX do YY"
>   「XXがYYしているのを見る」「XXがYYしているところを見る」 "see XX doing YY"

Examples:

- 山田さんが道を｛渡るのを/渡るところを｝見た。
  I saw Yamada-san cross the road.
- 山田さんが道を｛渡っているのを/渡っているところを｝見た。
  I saw Yamada-san crossing the road.
- (私は)佐藤くんが鈴木さんのコーヒーを飲むのを見ました。
  I saw Sato-kun drink Suzuki-san's coffee.
- (私は)佐藤くんが鈴木さんのコーヒーを飲んでいるのを見ました。
  I saw Sato-kun drinking Suzuki-san's coffee.

---

As for your first sentence:

> あの家に誰かいる**と**見た

"Sentence + quotative と + 見る" has a different meaning than "to see something/someone do(ing) ~~". 明鏡国語辞典 says:

> 見る
>    ⓫《「〜と見る」の形で、文を・・・受けて》周りの状況にてらして、ある判断を下す。「社長は今が規模拡張のチャンスだと見ている」

見る in "～～と見る" doesn't mean "to physically see something with your eyes", but "to judge", "presume", or "regard". For example:

- 我々は、遭難者のほとんどが死んだ**と見て**、捜索を打ち切った。
  We presumed that most of the victims were dead and gave up the search.
- 私は、この仕事には彼が適任**と見て**いる。
  I regard him to be the right person for this job.

As for your second sentence:

> あの家に誰かいることを見た

It doesn't really sound natural to me, I'm afraid.

Comment: Never seen ところ used like that before, what's the difference between it an の? What's the difference between 渡るの/渡ってるの? In English I would understand the first one as watching him successfully/ completely cross the road, while the second I don't know if succeed or not just that he were doing it. Is it the same in Japanese? Also isn't it odd to use the が with 誰か?

Comment: 1) ところ (所) literally means "place, spot", and here it adds the nuance of "(right) on the spot". eg 「今、本を読んでいる**ところ**です。」"I am reading a book now." 2) `Is it the same in Japanese?` -> Yes, I think it's usually the same. At least that's what I learned in my English class. 3) In 誰かいる, が is omitted. You know after 誰か, 何か etc., case particles such as を、が are often omitted, right? eg  誰か**を**紹介してよ -> 誰か紹介してよ。 何か**が**あるぞ -> 何かあるぞ。

Comment: Ok, so by often omitted I assume you mean it doesn't have to be omitted, like what you did in your answer. Thank you for your insights.

Comment: @Christer Oh now I see what you meant. Yes, 誰かがいるのを見た and 誰かいるのを見た are both fine. But 誰かが/誰かを/何かが/何かを sound unnatural/wrong in interrogative sentences, eg: "Is someone there?" would be 誰かいますか？ not 誰かがいますか？, "Did you see something?" would be 何か見ましたか？ not 何かを見ましたか？

Answer (score 4):

"I saw someone being in that house over there" is expressed as あの家に誰かいる**の**を見た.

あの家に誰かいると見た means that you have assumed that someone is in the house by observing the situation.

あの家に誰かいることを見た means that you considered a precondition that someone would be in the house. e.g. あの家にだれかいることを見て夕方に行くことにした: Considering someone would be in the house (then), I decided to go there evening.